# How to edit the string and add quotes in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have a problem with split string on python. For example I have a string that need to add some quotes on it.

Example string:

```py
word = "VITAMIN, HEALTH, SPORT"
```

And edit it to add some quotes on it into like this

```py
word = "'VITAMIN', 'HEALTH', 'SPORT'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
word = ", ".join(f"'{s}'" for s in word.split(", "))
print(word)
```

**Output**

```
'VITAMIN', 'HEALTH', 'SPORT'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
str(word.split(", "))[1:-1]
```

Or just do:

```
"'" + "', '".join(word.split(', ')) + "'"
```

Both solutions output:

```
'VITAMIN', 'HEALTH', 'SPORT'
```

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with `str` and slicing to remove the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes with `\'`.
So your code will be -

```
word = "\'VITAMIN\', \'HEALTH\', \'SPORT\'"
```

A article on escape characters
https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp

Answer (score 0):

One way that uses the fact that `str.__repr__` puts a string within single quotes (unless the string contains single quotes):

```
word = ", ".join(map(repr, word.split(", ")))
```

Docs on:

- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)